# How do I call a webservice using a script task in SSIS

Tags: web-services, ssis

I have to call a webservice method with parameter in an SSIS package without using the Web Service Task in 2005. However, no add web reference is coming there in the script component. How can I retrieve the methods available on a given webservice?

Answer (score 0):

If you have WSDL then you can use Add Service Reference to SSIS script task project. else you can create a client proxy class using svcutil.exe and create channelFactory method to create a proxy for you webservice and access your method.